# HelpIntent, CancelIntent, and StopIntent

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

This is my first certification. My skill is pretty simple. I've registered two handlers:

```
const handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function () {
      this.handler.state = "ASKMODE";
      this.emit(':ask',
                'Ask me to play a musical note, for example, say C sharp');
    },
    'Unhandled': function () {
        this.response.speak('I do not know how to proceed. Try asking for a note like, alexa, ask pitch pipe to give me a d flat.');
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'PlayPitch': function () {
        const noteSlot = this.event.request.intent.slots.Note;
        let noteName;
        if (noteSlot && noteSlot.value) {
            noteName = noteSlot.value.toLowerCase();
            var speech = resultingSpeech(noteName);
            this.response.speak(speech);
        }
        else {
            this.response.speak('I don\'t know that note.');
        }

        this.emit(':responseReady');
    }
};

const followUpHandlers = Alexa.CreateStateHandler("ASKMODE", {
    'PlayPitch': function () {
        const noteSlot = this.event.request.intent.slots.Note;
        let noteName;
        if (noteSlot && noteSlot.value) {
          noteName = noteSlot.value.toLowerCase();
          var speech = resultingSpeech(noteName);
          this.response.speak(speech);
        }
        else {
          const speechOutput = 'Pitch Pipe will play any note of the 12 tone scale surrounding A440 ';
          const reprompt = 'Simply speak the name of a note, such as e flat.';

          this.response.speak(speechOutput).listen(reprompt);
          this.emit(':responseReady');
        }

        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {
          const speechOutput = 'Pitch Pipe will play any note of the 12 tone scale surrounding A440 ';
          const reprompt = 'Simply speak the name of a note, such as e flat.';

          this.response.speak(speechOutput).listen(reprompt);
          this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
        this.response.speak('Goodbye!');
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
        this.response.speak('See you later!');
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    },
    'Unhandled': function () {
        this.response.speak('I think you asked for a note, but I don\'t understand.');
        this.emit(':responseReady');
    }
});
```

So the original LaunchRequest on handlers works appropriately and when it comes back in ASKMODE it goes to the followUpHandlers with a PitchPipe intent, which works fine as well.

The problem is in handling help/cancel/stop. If, while in ASKMODE, you say, "Help" it comes back into the PitchPipe intent with no value in the slot. I have hacked it to handle help for now, but can't figure out how this should really work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused by the fact that I had saved my interaction model, but not built it. Once I built the interaction model, everything worked perfectly.

Yikes!